# question about Inner

Tags: list-manipulation

question1:

(*code 1 something wrong, Why? and how to overcome this to achieve the next code's effect*)

```
Inner[RotationTransform,{Pi/4,Pi/4,Pi/4},{{0,0,1},{1,0,0},{0,0,1}},Composition]
```

(*code2 it's ok, but seems type too much characters*)

```
Inner[RotationTransform,{Pi/4,Pi/4,Pi/4},{xx,yy,zz},Composition]/.
                                           Thread[Rule[{xx,yy,zz},{{0,0,1},{1,0,0},{0,0,1}}]]
```

Any other codes or tips are welcome.

Comment: Use `Composition @@ MapThread[RotationTransform, {{Pi/4, Pi/4, Pi/4}, {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}}]` instead.

Comment: @J. M. 
ok,
I found this is more simpler in my original code'style.

Inner[RotationTransform,{Pi/4,Pi/4,Pi/4},Hold/@{{0,0,1},{1,0,0},{0,0,1}},Composition]//Release

Comment: `ReleaseHold[]` is what the cool kids use nowadays.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can just add `Unevaluated` to prevent `Inner` from seeing inside:

```
Inner[RotationTransform, {Pi/4, Pi/4, Pi/4}, 
 Unevaluated /@ {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, Composition]
```