# A matrix-vector cross product

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, vector

I want to do a cross product involving a vector of Pauli matrices $\vec \sigma  = \left( {{\sigma _1},{\sigma _2},{\sigma _3}} \right)$; for example, $\vec \sigma  \times \left( {1,2,3} \right)$.

```
s:= Table[PauliMatrix[i], {i, 1, 3}];
Cross[s,{1,2,3}]
```

The code above will not work.

The only way I can think of is to use the method which I have just learned from Mr. Wizard:

```
ReleaseHold @ Block[{PauliMatrix}, Hold @@ {Cross[s,{1, 2, 3}]}]
```

But I feel uncomfortable writing such long code to realize such a simple cross product.

Is there any better way or not?

---

**Update**
J.M. give the method

```
Cross[Unevaluated /@ PauliMatrix[Range[3]], {a,b,c}]
```

But it turns out that when one of the a,b,c is zero, the code will give error. a Remedy is given by J.M in his comment.

But I am asking here why it gives right answer when a b c are all nonzero while failed with a zero component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directly define a cross function should be the easiest.

```
cross3[{x_, y_, z_}, {a_, b_, c_}] := {c y - b z, -c x + a z, b x - a y}
```

then no matter

```
cross3[PauliMatrix[Range[3]],{1,2,3}]
```

or

```
cross3[{1,2,3},PauliMatrix[Range[3]]]
```

will be OK. No ordering problem in Jens' LeviCivitaTensor method.

Answer (score 6):

Another idea to shorten the notation for the cross product in the special case where you have a Pauli matrix vector as the first argument is this:

```
ClearAll[OverVector];
OverVector /: Cross[OverVector[σ], x_?VectorQ] := 
 x.LeviCivitaTensor[3].PauliMatrix[Range[3]]

Cross[OverVector[σ], {x, y, z}]

(*
==> {{{-y, -I z}, {I z, y}}, {{x, -z}, {-z, -x}}, {{0, 
   I x + y}, {-I x + y, 0}}}
*)
```

You can also literally enter $\vec{\sigma}$ instead of OverVector[σ].

If you want to make the definition of the cross product more visible in your notation, you could also introduce the `LeviCivitaTensor` in the form of an abbreviation $\varepsilon$ and use it instead of `Cross` directly:

```
ε = LeviCivitaTensor[3];

OverVector[σ] = PauliMatrix[Range[3]];

{x, y, z}.ε.OverVector[σ]

(*
==> {{{-y, -I z}, {I z, y}}, {{x, -z}, {-z, -x}}, {{0, 
   I x + y}, {-I x + y, 0}}}
*)
```

I've defined an abbreviation for the vector of Pauli matrices here. Because of this, the two approaches (this one and the first alternative) don't mix - so one should settle on or the other.

**Edit in response to updated question**

The `Unevaluated` trick in J.M.'s answer works without error in version 8 (that's where I tested it first, and upvoted that method initially). But it produces *divide-by-zero* errors in version 9. This seems like a bug to me because there are no documented changes in `Cross` or `Unevaluated` in recent versions. My `LeviCivitaTensor` approach works in all versions.

Comment: For people like me who've forgotten their identities: `{p, q, r}.LeviCivitaTensor[3].{u, v, w} === Cross[{u, v, w}, {p, q, r}]`. Note the order!

Comment: @J.M. BTW, a related answer where I used this is: [Is it possible to do vector calculus in Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19707/245). Hope you don't get into an identity crisis...

Answer (score 6):

Taking a page from [kptnw's fine answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24627), here's one possibility:

```
Cross[Unevaluated /@ PauliMatrix[Range[3]], Range[3]]
```

Comment: I finally choose your answer. easier and won't have to worry about the order and negtive sign when using LeviCivitaTensor

Comment: OhOh, Sorry J.M. I found peculier things. Your solution is flawed. Try Cross[Unevaluated/@PauliMatrix[Range[3]],{0,1,0}]

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. In that case, `Cross[Unevaluated /@ PauliMatrix[Range[3]], {\[FormalP], \[FormalQ], \[FormalR]}] /. Thread[{\[FormalP], \[FormalQ], \[FormalR]} -> {0, 1, 0}]`

Comment: Ok, rule replacement works. But I still don't know where does it gone wrong? I looked into the `Trace` result, but it is unexpectedly long! I can't figure out why.

Comment: FWIW the referenced question is a duplicate.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, huh, I forgot that older question... you're right!

Answer (score 3):

Since I'm being credited with the method (which I do appreciate), let me point out that your use of `Block` is being needlessly complicated with `Hold` and `ReleaseHold`.  The same behavior can be had with:

```
Block[{PauliMatrix}, Cross[s, {1, 2, 3}]]
```

> ```
> {{{-2, -3 I}, {3 I, 2}}, {{1, -3}, {-3, -1}}, {{0, 2 + I}, {2 - I, 0}}}
> ```

---

We can make the `Unevaluated` method, similar to what I showed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9219/121) and what J. M. posted above, work even with vectors containing zero by applying it to all elements.  I would write it thus:

```
heldCross[vec__] := Cross @@ Map[Unevaluated, {vec}, {2}]
```

Now:

```
heldCross[PauliMatrix @ Range @ 3, {1, 2, 3}]
```

> ```
> {{{-2, -3 I}, {3 I, 2}}, {{1, -3}, {-3, -1}}, {{0, 2 + I}, {2 - I, 0}}}
> ```

```
heldCross[PauliMatrix @ Range @ 3, {0, 1, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{{-1, -2 I}, {2 I, 1}}, {{0, -2}, {-2, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}}
> ```

Comment: Happy to see you! Thank you very much! you're right, I realized how stupid I am at that time. But this method only works in the situation when `s` is setdeleyed as `Table[PauliMatrix[i],{3}]`, it will not gonna work if `s` is not setdeleyed or `PauliMatix[Range[3]]. So let me just stick with my answer below, it is quite straightforward which makes it seems a little "silly", but to my experience, it is quite robust.

Comment: @matheorem Hardly stupid; a mere mistake. :-)  Normally I [would have recommended](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9219/121) `Unevaluated` as J. M. did, but I see that method breaks with zeros.  I am looking into that now.  (The `Trace` is indeed long.)

Comment: Awesome. But can you explain why J.M.'s solution is flawed when there is zero. By the way, J.M. changed his name to 0x4A4D??!!!

Comment: @matheorem I didn't see anything obvious and I didn't feel like working on it right now.  Yes, he did; I guess he's feeling [pallid.](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/4A4D/index.htm)

Comment: So it is a chinese character. Wow, that's interesting. I know a lot of chinese characters, actually I am a chinese. But I can bet, this character is not known by 99.99% chinese people.

Answer (score 2):

Much has already been said about this problem, but maybe this solution still might be helpful.

First we define an auxiliary vector

```
In[18]:= va = Array[a, 3]

Out[18]= {a[1], a[2], a[3]}
```

with which it is trivial to calculate the cross product:

```
In[19]:= Cross[va, {1, 2, 3}]

Out[19]= {3 a[2] - 2 a[3], -3 a[1] + a[3], 2 a[1] - a[2]}
```

Now we replace the components of va by the Pauli matrices which gives us the final result

```
In[20]:= % /. Table[a[i] -> PauliMatrix[i], {i, 1, 3}]

Out[20]= {{{-2, -3 I}, {3 I, 2}}, {{1, -3}, {-3, -1}}, {{0, 2 + I}, {2 - I, 0}}}
```

In compact form, and for an arbitrary vector {u,v,w} instead of {1,2,3} we have

```
In[41]:= Cross[
  Array[a, 3], {u, v, w}] /. ((a[#] -> PauliMatrix[#]) & /@ Range[3])

Out[41]= {{{-v, -I w}, {I w, v}}, {{u, -w}, {-w, -u}}, {{0, I u + v}, {-I u + v, 0}}}
```

Regards,
Wolfgang

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method that uses LeviCivita and defines the cross product in terms of its [index notation expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Index_notation_for_tensors):

```
Cr[ms_, a_] := Map[Sum[
    LeviCivitaTensor[3][[#, j, k]] ms[[j]] a[[k]], 
    {j, Range[3]}, 
    {k, Range[3]}
    ] &, Range[3]] /; 3 == Length[ms] == Length[a]
```

In dimensions other than 3, the analogously defined cross product is not a vector, so this definition is meaningless in that case.

```
Cr[PauliMatrix /@ Range[3], {1, 2, 3}]
    (* {{{-2, -3 I}, {3 I, 2}}, {{1, -3}, {-3, -1}}, {{0, 2 + I}, {2 - I, 0}}} *)
Cr[a /@ Range[3], b /@ Range[3]]
    (* {-a[3] b[2] + a[2] b[3], a[3] b[1] - a[1] b[3], -a[2] b[1] + a[1] b[2]} *)
```